# how to save a different domain in laravel app and the app will accessable from the domain

Tags: laravel

I am developing a customers service based laravel application. 
where customer can save their own domain. and the application should accessible from the individual customer saved domain (just like domain parking). how to make this system ? please help me.

Comment: Which part of this are you struggling with? Is it having your application recognise a user based on their domain, having the domain resolve to your application, or something else entirely (if so please add an explanation).

Comment: actually i am developing a  e-commerce system.  my customer  store open their in my application. they will get a interface where they can park their own domain.  i think you should understand what i am saying.

Comment: Ok. I understood what you're trying to achieve. My question is what part of this are you struggling with? What don't you know how to do or what part of the process isn't working?

Comment: Look i have no knowledge about this types of system. the system will be a multi-store e-commerce platform in which a customer would be able to open his own shop. at first he will get a subdomain like "user1.myshop.com"  and the subdomain will be use to access his store opened in "myshop.com".  but if the user have his own domain (ex: userstore.com), he can park the domain in his dashboard of (user1.myshop.com)  and "user1.myshop.com" will accessible directly from "userstore.com". this is the system i want develop.